# Setting access rights for a directory - receiving exception "No flags can be set"

Tags: c#, security

I am trying to progamrtaiclly allow write access to ASPNET account on a directory. I am using the following code to do this: (Please note that I want the "write access allowed" for ASPNET to be propagated to the child objects as well:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {


                FileSecurity fileSecurity;

                fileSecurity = new FileSecurity();

                fileSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);

                fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("ASPNET",FileSystemRights.Write,InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit|InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,AccessControlType.Allow));                                   

                File.SetAccessControl("C:\\TestDir1", fileSecurity);
            }
```

This code is resulting in the exception: "No flags can be set.\r\nParameter name: inheritanceFlags"

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the solution, apparently I would have to do it this way:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\TestDir2");
            DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

            dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("ASPNET", FileSystemRights.Write|FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));


            dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
```

Comment: It appears that setting inheritance flags doesn't work unless an existing FileSecurity object is used? This doesn't make testing any easier.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, the original problem was that you were using the `FileSecurity` class (which applies to files, not directories) and attempting to set the ACL for a directory, but this can happen for any of the following reasons as well:

1. When setting a rule for a **directory**, you specify
   `InheritanceFlags.None` as the inheritance flag, but supply any
   value other than `PropagationFlags.None` for the propagation flag
   (you can't propagate inheritance that doesn't exist).
2. When setting a rule for a **file**, specify any value other than
   `InheritanceFlags.None` and `PropragationFlags.None` for the
   respective parameters (files are not containers, and so inheritance
   cannot be specified).

You can see the relevant checks that the .NET Framework does in the [source for the CheckFlags method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/accesscontrol/acl.cs,1972).